# Parse string surrounded by group

Tags: .net, regex, markdown

I am trying to un-markdown text, but keep its markup. For example, I have string like:

```
![my photo description](http://site.com/directory/subdir/my __image_of_something.jpg
"My image title"). Lorem ipsum *dolor sit amet*, __consectetur adipisicing__ elit,
_sed do_ eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et __dolore magna aliqua__.
```

I using regex pattern `\s+[\*_]{1,2}(.*)[\*_]{1,2}` but it is also takes wrong entries started with space and double underscore and ended where correct entry started.

How to compose regex which meets following requirements:

- it may started with single or double asterisk or single or double underscore.
- it must be non-greedy (marked with '?').
- it must ended with the exactly same group which it is started.

Comment: **Non**-greedy = `?`, so there's probably an error in the 2nd point. Try `\s+([*_]{1,2})(.*)\1`.

Comment: @Dukeling wow, it is awesome! Of course, you are absolutely right about greediness of qualifier.

Comment: can you list out what do you want from your sample code?

Comment: Actually something like `\*\*?|__?` instead of `[*_]{1,2}` might be better, otherwise _*abc_* would be valid. And what about recursive defitions: `__**abc**__` or `__ab**cd**ef__`?